# FBLoginView read permissions doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook, iphone-6

I created an app which asks user to login with Facebook. This part of code was working totally perfect on each device:

```
self.facebookButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
self.facebookButton.delegate = self;
```

But I found that it doesn't work on iPhone 6 (device or simulator). Error is about method

```
[UIButton setReadPermissions:] unrecognized selector.
```

Anyone help me, I just have no idea what it can be and how I can fix it

Comment: You probably have a different button instance for larger screens and the button there is a standard UIButton and not the Facebookbutton subclass.

Comment: It's a string from .h file - @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet FBLoginView *facebookButton; so it's Facebookbutton subclass

Comment: aaaa, I understood what you mean. But how can I handle this?? Can I create FBLoginView for smaller screen or how? Sorry, I'm totally confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, guys, I've figured it out. I had the problem with UIController (didn't connect login view with outlet). I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the `self.facebookButton` is the instance of `FBLoginView`. if yes, please 
declare it as `strong`.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet FBLoginView *facebookButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I'll leave my solution here in case it helps someone out. I'd changed the class on the `Main.storyboard` to be a `FBSDKButton` instead of a `UIButton`, but there was another storyboard file localized to Spanish that still had it as a `UIButton`.